# Shiny - overlapping absolutePanel and table

Tags: shiny

I have a shiny-app which has a leaflet map, and some data on an absolutePanel. 
I also have a table below the map. The problem is when I scroll down to view the table, the absolutePanel comes down too and overlaps with the table. I would like the absolutePanel to stay on top and not come down when I scroll down to view the table. Anyway to fix this?

Code for absolutePanel:

```
absolutePanel(id = "controls", class = "panel panel-default", fixed = TRUE, 
                  style="padding-left: 8px; padding-right: 8px; padding-top: 8px; padding-bottom: 8px",
                  draggable = TRUE, top = 126, left = "auto", right = 20, bottom = "auto",
                  width = 250, height = "auto", #data goes here)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed `fixed = FALSE` which keeps the absolutePanel where it is and doesn't move it relative to the page.